# Booking Date Ranges for each month separately

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a scenario to play per year:

Booking table records:

agent_id       start_dt          end_dt         created_on   hotel_id   description

---------        2012-02-27   2012-03-05       ------           -------       ----------

---------        2012-06-02   2012-06-04       ------           -------       ----------

---------        2012-03-28   2012-04-02       ------           -------       ----------

---------        2012-08-22   2012-09-10       ------           -------       ----------

After having this table, Now I want to have separate dates for each month for specific year only like 2012 or might be 2013;

> **January**: no dates

> **February**: 2012-02-27, 2012-02-28

> **March**: 2012-03-1, 2012-03-2, 2012-03-3, 2012-03-4, 2012-03-5,
>   2012-03-28, 2012-03-29, 2012-03-30, 2012-03-31

> **April**: 2012-04-1, 2012-04-2

> **May**: Indeed no dates

> **June**: 2012-06-2, 2012-06-3, 2012-06-4

> **July**: Indeed no dates

> **August**: 2012-08-22, 2012-08-23, 2012-08-24, 2012-08-25, 2012-08-26,
>   2012-08-27, 2012-08-28, 2012-08-29, 2012-08-30, 2012-08-31

> **September**: 2012-09-1, 2012-09-2, 2012-09-3, 2012-09-4, 2012-09-5,
>   2012-09-6, 2012-09-7, 2012-09-8, 2012-09-9, 2012-09-10

> **October**: no date

> **November**: no date

> **December**: no date

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: There are various solutions, some which require the construction of utility tables and/or complex UNION queries, and some which simply fill in the blanks using application level code (e.g. PHP).

My preference would probably be a combination of PHP (for grouping the results and filling in missing months) and a MySQL utility table - in this case a calendar table holding all relevant dates, for returning all dates between start and end.

Comment: BTW, 2012 was a leap year ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want MySQL to calculate it for you,

To get all start_dt :

```
SELECT group_concat(start_dt) as all_start_date, DATE_FORMAT(start_dt,'%M') as month 
FROM `your_table_name` 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(start_dt,'%M')
```

To get all end_dt (simply change all start_dt to end_dt) :

```
SELECT group_concat(end_dt) as all_end_date, DATE_FORMAT(end_dt,'%M') as month 
FROM `your_table_name` 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(end_dt,'%M')
```

If you want to add specific condition like only in year 2012, you should add :

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start_dt,'%Y') = '2012'
```

before GROUP BY ... so it will be something like this,

```
SELECT group_concat(start_dt) as all_start_date, DATE_FORMAT(start_dt,'%M') as month 
FROM `your_table_name` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start_dt,'%Y') = '2012' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(start_dt,'%M')
```

Comment: I will try it by Monday, then get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, i'll wait for your response.. Btw, if you want, you can use 'DISTINCT' inside group_concat() to get rid of duplicate date on the same month. ;)

Comment: **I am receiving this result only while it is not taking out start to end range. just playing with start dates only.**
'
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-04-01,2013-04-08
    [all_start_date] => 2013-04-01,2013-04-08
    [1] => April
    [month] => April
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-07-29
    [all_start_date] => 2013-07-29
    [1] => July
    [month] => July
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-03-15
    [all_start_date] => 2013-03-15
    [1] => March
    [month] => March
)'

Comment: **Results are below, rsults are only start date based, not from start to end date range. (I have quite diffirent records in DB like "2013-03-15 to 2013-03-18" , "2013-04-01 to 2013-04-04" , "2013-04-08 to 2013-04-10" , "2013-07-29 to 2013-08-03")**
'
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-04-01,2013-04-08
    [all_start_date] => 2013-04-01,2013-04-08
    [1] => April
    [month] => April
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-07-29
    [all_start_date] => 2013-07-29
    [1] => July
    [month] => July
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-03-15
    [all_start_date] => 2013-03-15
    [1] => March
    [month] => March
)'

Comment: The result is correct according to the query above. So, what did you want to achieve actually ?

Answer (score 0):

Select all dates from mysql and then for each row calculate the dates in between with [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) put each date into second two-dimensional array with the month id as the key

```
$reservations_by_month = [];
foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
    $begin = new DateTime($reservation['start_dt']);
    $end = new DateTime($reservation['end_dt']);
    $end = $end->modify('+1 day'); 

    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    foreach($daterange as $date){
        $month = $date->format('m');
        if (!is_array($reservations_by_month[$month])) $reservations_by_month[$month] = [];
        $reservations_by_month[$month][] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all of your response. Being a professional, we will not have 4 or 50 or 1000 records so no manual loop practise but only if MySQL can do this job, because we are going to deal with more than 1 million records. I hope you do understand. :)